# How does one remove (unregister) a runtime (not component) from the NoFlo Development Environment

Tags: noflo

I am running a local version of the NoFlo Development Environment and would like to know how to remove (unregister) a runtime. Actually, how can I remove a runtime from the FlowHub hosted environment, as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no UI to do this, but the API exists: [Issue](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui/issues/417)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my bash script for doing just that.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# Your UUID can be found through developer JS console: Resources -> Local Storage -> Look for grid-token
uuid="<your uuid>" 

# the list of runtimes you want to delete.
list=$1

for i in ${list}
do
    curl -X DELETE http://api.flowhub.io/runtimes/${i} -H "Authorization: Bearer ${uuid}"
done
```